# update 2 dropdown with same data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to update values from one table into 2 dropdowns with different id's. but only one dropdown has values and other dropdown is empty.
Where am I going wrong.
If I am using two different methods its working but I dont want duplicate code.

```
function updateDropDown(){     
         var DD1 = "#DD1",TempChild = null;
         var DD2= '#DD2';
         var Data= Table.getLength();
         $(DD1).html('');
         $(DD2).html('');
            for(var i =0;i<Data;i++){
               TempChild= document.createElement('option');
               TempChild.value =  Table.getItem(i).id;
               TempChild.innerHTML = Table.getItem(i).name;
               $(DD1).append(TempChild);
               $(DD2).append(TempChild);
               TempChild = null;
           }
     }
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [Why do multiple `.appendTo` calls on a newly created jQuery element only append it once?](/q/5529091/4642212), but this is a special case where you use the “Node” function signature of `append`. It works the same way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Though TempChild is an element having a single copy of it. It can be placed in a single place. So to put the same inside another element either you need to create a similar element using document.createElement or just clone it.

Do like this

```
function updateDropDown(){     
         var DD1 = "#DD1",TempChild = null;
         var DD2= '#DD2';
         var Data= Table.getLength();
         $(DD1).html('');
         $(DD2).html('');
            for(var i =0;i<Data;i++){
               TempChild= document.createElement('option');
               TempChild.value =  Table.getItem(i).id;
               TempChild.innerHTML = Table.getItem(i).name;
               $(DD1).append(TempChild);
               $(DD2).append(TempChild.cloneNode(true));
               TempChild = null;
           }
     }
```

Comment: cloneNode is adding two blank options.

Comment: Do $(DD2).append(TempChild.cloneNode(true));

Answer (score 0):

You can't append the same element (TempChild) in two different other elements (DD1 and DD2). TempChild is unique. You have to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the created element was already inserted. One way to do it is clone the node or create `HTML` as a string and insert it.

Also I prefer creating the options as a string instead of creating a node on every iteration as that might hit some performance when the data array is too big;

```
function updateDropDown() {
    var DD1 = "#DD1",
        TempChild = null,
        DD2 = '#DD2',
        Data = Table.getLength();

    $(DD1).html('');
    $(DD2).html('');
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < Data; i++) {
        options +=
            '<option value="' + Table.getItem(i).id + '">' + Table.getItem(i).name + '</option>';
    }

    $(DD1).append(options);
    $(DD2).append(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [$.clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and first create the array of options instead of writing to the DOM on every loop

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/JdamVo?editors=101)**

```
var DD1 = "#DD1",
      TempChild = null,
      DD2 = '#DD2',
      Data = [], 
      options = [];;

  Data.push({id: 'test',name: 'test'});
  Data.push({id: 'test1',name: 'test1'});


  for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
    TempChild = document.createElement('option');
    TempChild.value = Data[i].id;
    TempChild.text = Data[i].name;
    options.push(TempChild);
    TempChild = null;
  }
  $(DD1).append(options);
  $(DD2).append($(options).clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **jquery** like you're **tagged** in your question, why not profiting the magic and reduce your code to :

**JQuery code :**

```
updateDropDown = function(){
    for(var i =0;i<Table.getLength();i++){
        TempChild=$('<option></option>').val(Table.getItem(i).id).text(Table.getItem(i).name);

        $("#DD1").html(TempChild);
        $("#DD2").html(TempChild);

        TempChild = null;
    }
}
```

That will solve your problem and reducing code in same time, good luck.